spark on EMR error when using `foreachBatch`: "terminated with exception: Error while obtaining a new communication channel"
I use spark on EMR with versions: emr-6.13.0, Spark 3.4.1
i try to run a simple spark streaming job that read from kafka and write to memory-table using foreachBatch and get failure "Error while obtaining a new communication channel".
detailed error:
Fail to execute line 54: query.awaitTermination()
<some more text>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 175, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = 0f1c0ee6-5d67-4e10-a239-515c60777efc, runId = 3c4b5b12-0df9-4d45-81e3-b017f71a787b] terminated with exception: Error while obtaining a new communication channel

it's very important to say that when i don't use foreachBatch i can read data from kafka and write to memory without any problem. the error start when i use the foreachBatch
the pyspark script:
%pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, MapType, BooleanType, StructField

KAFKA_TOPIC = "data.eventflow.enriched-events"
KAFKA_BROKERS = "myKafkaBroker"

# Create a Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("BasicKafkaRead") \
    .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define the schema for the JSON data from Kafka
schema = StructType([
    StructField("event_id", StringType()),
    StructField("event_name", StringType()),
    StructField("created_at", StringType()),
    StructField("user_id", StringType()),
    StructField("game_id", StringType()),
    StructField("event_payload", MapType(StringType(), StringType())),
    StructField("user_payload", MapType(StringType(), StringType())),
    StructField("game_payload", MapType(StringType(), StringType())),
    StructField("is_known_bot", BooleanType())
])

# Read from Kafka
kafkaDataFrame = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BROKERS) \
    .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
    .load()

def process_batch(batch_df, batch_id):
    # Parse the JSON data
    parsed_df = batch_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as jsonValue") \
        .select(from_json(col("jsonValue"), schema).alias("data"))
    
    # Write batch to a memory table
    parsed_df.write.format("memory").queryName("parsed_kafka_data").mode("append").save()

# Apply foreachBatch to process each micro-batch
query = kafkaDataFrame.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(process_batch) \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .trigger(processingTime="10 seconds") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()

